# (Android) I can't make depth buffer work in opengl es2

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I already spent several hours trying to make depth buffer work, but no luck.
Initialization code:

```
class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
public BasicGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    [...]
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    [...]
    m_rend = new ViewRenderer(context, m_app);
    setRenderer(m_rend);
}
```

rendering funcrtion looks like this:

```
public void Render() {
        [...]
    GLES20.glClearColor(m_backColor.x(), m_backColor.y(), m_backColor.z(), 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        [...]
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL);
    GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
    GLES20.glDepthRangef(m_depthNear, m_depthFar);
        [...]
        [...rendering...]
}
```

I assume that there are two things can be wrong: first is depth buffer wasn't initialized successfully, but setEGLConfigChooser returns no error, and second if I setup rendering states incorrrectly. What's wrong with my code?

BTW. I've made it work in my NativeActivity project, but i can't do the same in java :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please define what 'not work' means exactly. Also what is your 'depthNear/depthFar' set to? Have you tested errors with glGetError?

Comment: Not work means that it draws like there is no depth buffer at all. And yes, I tried glGetLastError, please, read the question carefully.

Comment: The problem was solved by rebooting my galaxy tab and restarting Eclipse... In other words, it wasn't actually application bug, but troubles somewhere in Eclipse or Android SDK internals.